# npm install oracledb errors

Tags: node.js, npm, node-oracledb

I try install oracledb with npm but I got errors.
Installed:

- OS: Windows 10 x64
- Python: 2.7
- Npm: 5.3.0
- Node: v8.3.0
- Oracle: 11g instant client.

Environments:

- Path: C:\oracle\instantclient_11_2
- Path: C:\Program Files\nodejs\
- Path: C:\Python27
- OCI_INC_DIR: C:\oracle\instantclient_11_2\sdk\include
- OCI_LIB_DIR: C:\oracle\instantclient_11_2\sdk\lib\msvc

Command:

[Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXYty.png)

Log Errors: [Logs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzK6kPtaAWN8WkRyR1FNR3ZObVE)

Comment: Please update your question and include the errors. Also, explain what you're trying to do; What commands are giving you errors?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXYty.png, I got that command, I tried command: npm install oracledb. Sorry, my english very bad! T_T T_T

Comment: try this - https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-931127

Comment: @Aky_0788 I was tried! :'( :'(

Comment: The place to ask node-oracledb installation questions is the GitHub issue forum https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues

Comment: @Aky_0788 I installed success. T_T reinstall windows and try this  community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-931127 --> success. Tks everyone. Close it.